# Matrix Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'm trying to solve this exercise:
Let G⊂GL(n,R) be a subgroup.  Prove that G is a Lie
group if and only if it is a closed subset of GL(n,R) in the relative topology.

I thing I have to use the fact that G is a subgroup hence the multiplication is closed as an operation in G in order to show it is also a closed set in the topological sense, but I'm stuck here. Any suggestions (also for the other direction) ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_subgroup_theorem

Comment: This is not an elementary theorem; if you are asked how to prove it as a part of a homework, you should explain which textbook are you following and what material did you already cover, etc.

Comment: Thank you ... was an exercise in the note of my professor I will ask him directly then ! https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf exercise 2.6.13